# How to avoid double free or corruption (fasttop) on copy assignment operators?

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, double-free

I have the following class, where I force the compiler to generate all the copy/move constructors and assignment operators.

```
class foo {
public:
    float *x;
    size_t size;
    foo(int m){
        size = m;
        x = new float[size];}

    foo(const foo&) = default;
    foo(foo&&) = default;
    foo& operator =(const foo&) = default;
    foo& operator =(foo&&) = default;

    ~foo(){delete [] x;}

    void fill(const float& num)
    {
        std::fill(x,x+size,num);
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (auto i=0;i<size;++i)
            cout << x[i] << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

Then I call it from the `main` function, like this

```
int main()
{
    foo x(2);
    x.fill(6);
    x.print();


    foo y(2);
    y = x; // causes the error

    return x;
}
```

Now I know I am freeing the memory twice by assigning `y = x`; so once one is freed the other is `null`, am I right? I went ahead and implemented my own copy assignment operator

```
foo& operator=(const foo& other)
{
    if (other.x!=x)
        x = other.x;
    return *this;
}
```

However, I guess here again I am doing what the default constructor is doing anyway. My question is how to make a proper copy assignment operator  so that this problem does not happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<float[]> x;` would solve your double-free and provide correct destruction, move construction and move assignment automatically.  And force you to be intentional about defining the copy operation (it would be deleted by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy not the pointer, but the contents of the pointer. A good approach to use is the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) since your copy constructor should already do the work of copying the contents of `x`:

```
friend void swap(foo& first, foo& second)
{
    using std::swap; 
    swap(first.x, second.x); 
    swap(first.size, second.size);
}

foo& operator=(foo other) // note pass by value
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to memcpy the pointer instead? Would that also solve the problem?

Comment: @chhadd: Not in the general case, because `size` may be different. Consider: `foo f(10), g(2); g = f;`. You would be able to do it if you assign to an equal size or less, but you'd still have to be able to account for the general case.